# Thread WaitReason.UserRequest

Tags: c#, multithreading

A Windows Service uses too many threads. I added some logging to find out more. Sadly, there's little support from the .Net framework.

`ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);` starts with some 32760 workerThreads, and 1000 completionThreads, resp.

After a few hours, available `workerThreads` went down to 31817, i.e. almost 1000 `managed threads` are in use.

What are they doing? There's no way to find out (you may find some workaround where you place the threads you create into some collection, and later analyze that collection, but that fails when you also use `Parellel.ForEach` or `Task.Run`).

Well, there is another possibility. Try `ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;` That will give you a list of `non-managed threads` (there number is also shown in Windows Task Manager).

My Windows Service starts with some 20 of them. After a few hours, I detect 3828, i.e. about 4 non-managed threads for each managed thread...

Now I can ask each of them when it started, what its priority is, what it is doing currently, and why it is waiting. Yes, for almost all of them the current state is `Wait`. And the `WaitReason` is in most cases `UserRequest`.

So my question is: what are those threads actually doing? There is no User Interface, even no command line associated with that executable: it is a Windows Service...

Also, I'd like to know how to get rid off them: many threads are created and should also run to completion in a short time (within seconds) - but some are "waiting" for hours.

Comment: Use the debugger, the Debug > Windows > Threads window is important to find out what these threads are doing.  You'll see more when you also enable unmanaged debugging, just in case your program uses some kind of unmanaged library.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that issue by using the rationale that a thread which is not created cannot hang around uselessly.

I removed some calls to `Parallel.Foreach(collection, item => { item.DoSomething(parameters); } );`. Now implementations of `IItem.DoSomething(parameters)` just enqueue the parameters for later processing, and `IItem`s have a thread for that processing (Active Object Pattern). Consequently, a "common" `foreach` can be used.

When results need to be collected, the pattern is more complicated:

```
private List<IResult> CollectResults(IEnumerable<IItem> collection, int maximumProcessingMilliseconds )
{
    List<IResult> results = new List<IResult>();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(maximumProcessingMilliseconds);

    var tasks = new List<Task<IResult>>();
    foreach (IItem item in collection)
    {
        IItem localItem = item;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => localItem.GetResult(cts.Token), cts.Token));
    }
    Task[] tasksArray = tasks.ToArray();
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasksArray, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(maximumProcessingMilliseconds));
        Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
    }

    foreach (Task<IResult> task in tasks)
    {
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            results.Add(task.Result);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

This is a terrible lot of boiler plate code which obfuscates the actual meaning of the function.

In the end, the number of (unmanaged) threads used by the application hardly ever grows beyond 100, and if it did, it does return to lower values quickly.